# Axios GET request with JSON, req.body on server is empty

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

I am trying to make a get request with JSON payload, but the data never gets to the server, req.body is empty.

```
  async function getConfig() {
    try {
      const retrievedConfig = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:3000/config/one",
        {
          Name: "Hello",
        }
      );
      console.log(retrievedConfig);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error");
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I have tried stringifying it, I have also tried adding headers as a third argument { headers } taken from this question here [Post request with axios and json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503283/post-request-with-axios-and-json-data)

```
  const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization",
  };
```

But no matter what I do, req.body on the server side is empty.

If I do (in the same function):

```
const retrievedConfig = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/config/all");
console.log(retrievedConfig);
```

To get all configs, it works and I do get the configs, so the problem should be with how I am sending the JSON object.

The same request with Postman works as intended, with the same json payload. http://prntscr.com/twizp9

**P.S.** This is axios on the front end (react) trying to get data from the backend (node)

Comment: the `data` parameter is "Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'" https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios get in url works but with second parameter as object it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947650/axios-get-in-url-works-but-with-second-parameter-as-object-it-doesnt)

Comment: `Axios` work little different (options are little different). That might the reason why it's working in `postaman` and not with `axios` request.

Comment: @PrathapReddy yes that worked, thanks.